# How do I get the number of elements from a list which is in a map?

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm programming a student administration so far and want to sort courses by their number descending and ascending.

The student.class wields a list which I store my students in. Should look like this.

```
    public class courses{
        Coursenumber coursenumber;
        int grade;
        Teacher teacher;
    
        List<Student> listOfStudentsInCourse = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I'm putting that list in a map for easier access to the key-value pairs.

```
TreeMap<Coursenumber, Course> showAllCoursesMap = new TreeMap<>();

        Course testCourse1 = new Klasse(
                new Coursenumber("XYZ"),
                grade 5,
                mrLee);

        Course testCourse1 = new Klasse(
                new Coursenumber("XYZ"),
                grade 5,
                mrSmith);
```

I added both of them in the showAllCoursesMap by using the put-method. The output should look like

```
testcourse1 number of students: 2
testcourse2 number of students: 1
```

Comment: `testCourse1` and `testCourse2` are variable names, so you can’t access (or output) those at run-time.   You could instead output the course number , except your example has those both having the same value `XYZ`, so not much use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stream API for Java >= Java 8.
Essentially what you want to do is some sorting based on Map values. Therefore we stream the map using `sorted` and compare based on the value using `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`. This method takes a `Comparator` which we can provide by using `Comparator.comparingInt()`. We then only have to tell `comparingInt()` what the key is we want to compare on. In your case that's the length of the List so you need to get the list and its size. Last but not least collect the results in a list.

If you want the List sorted in reversed order add `Collections.reverseOrder()`.

Here a minimal example that shows how you can could do it. The result will be of type `List<Map.Entry<Integer, Application.Wrapper>>` in my case. If you just want a list of the actual values (`List<Application.Wrapper>` in my case) you need to insert `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)` before `toList()`

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var test = new TreeMap<Integer, Wrapper>();
        test.put(1, new Wrapper(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)));
        test.put(2, new Wrapper(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4)));
        test.put(3, new Wrapper(List.of(1, 2)));
        test.put(4, new Wrapper(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));

        // sort in ascending order (default)
        var resultAscending = test
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(wrapper -> wrapper.getSomeList().size())))
                .toList();

        // sort in descending order
        var resultDescending = test
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                // only change here: Collections.reverseOrder()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(wrapper -> wrapper.getSomeList().size()))))
                .toList();

        System.out.println(resultAscending);
        System.out.println(resultDescending);
    }


    static class Wrapper {
        List<Integer> someList;

        public Wrapper(List<Integer> someList) {
            this.someList = someList;
        }

        public List<Integer> getSomeList() {
            return someList;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return someList + " (Size: %d)".formatted(someList.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
[3=[1, 2] (Size: 2), 2=[1, 2, 3, 4] (Size: 4), 1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (Size: 6), 4=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] (Size: 9)]
[4=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] (Size: 9), 1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (Size: 6), 2=[1, 2, 3, 4] (Size: 4), 3=[1, 2] (Size: 2)]
```

> Please note: The `toString()` method uses `formatted()` which is available starting from Java 15, so if you do not have that use `String.format(" Size: (%d)", someList.size())` instead of `" (Size: %d)".formatted(someList.size())` or drop that formatting completely as it was only added for demo purposes here.

Comment: Thank you so much! But what if I wanted to sort the list after the first name of my students? Instead of comparing the actual elements within the list? And is there a way to avoid streams?